# Compiling source Qt 4.7.4 on windows 7 error  qmake is not an internal or external command

Tags: c++, qt, installation, qt4.7

**Edit 2 -**

I don't have the application file qmake in the /bin folder and this is the error I am getting.

**Path environment variable :**  C:\development\referencebuilds\qt\4.7.4\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.4\bin\

**Command Prompt -** visual studio 2005

**Source folder** - C:\development\referencebuilds\qt\4.7.4\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.4

Steps -

1. Downloaded src
2. Extracted the files to folder – qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.4(C:\development\referencebuilds\qt\4.7.4)
3. configure.exe -opensource -fast -no-accessibility -no-qt3support -no-multimedia -no-audio-backend -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-webkit -no-scripttools -platform win32-msvc2005 -D “_BIND_TO_CURRENT_VCLIBS_VERSION=1”

4.nmake

The error I get is

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 8.00.50727.762
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

```
    C:\development\referencebuilds\qt\4.7.4\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7
```

.4\bin\qmake C:/development/referencebuilds/qt/4.7.4/qt-everywhere-opensource-sr
c-4.7.4/\projects.pro  -o Makefile -spec win32-msvc2005
'C:\development\referencebuilds\qt\4.7.4\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.4\bin\
qmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\development\referencebuilds\qt\4.7.4\qt-everywher
e-opensource-src-4.7.4\bin\qmake' : return code '0x1'
Stop.

### I know I dont have the app files for qmake and many other appfiles in my \bin folder. How do I get them?

---

**Edit 1**
Well, after trying out all the answers, the situation still remains the same. I think i should add more details to what I am doing.

**I am copying bin files(.dll , Appplication, Application Extension, Incremental Linker File, Program Debug Database, ) from another machine and the version of Qt was 4.7.2**

My questions are - 
1. Do you see that as the cause for all the issues here? If yes, how do I get all the above files? If I just congigure as above and then run nmake I get

> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 8.00.50727.762
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> ```
>     C:\development\referencebuilds\qt\4.7.4\bin\qmake
> ```
>
> C:/development/referen cebuilds/qt/4.7.4/\projects.pro  -o Makefile
>   -spec win32-msvc2008
>   'C:\development\referencebuilds\qt\4.7.4\bin\qmake' is not recognized
>   as an inte rnal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>   NMAKE : fatal error U1077:
>   'C:\development\referencebuilds\qt\4.7.4\bin\qmake' :  return code
>   '0x1' Stop.

---

1, Downloaded the source file named

`qt-everywhere-opensource-4.7.4` and saved it in folder `c:\development\referencebuilds\qt\4.7.4\`

2, uncompressed the zip file and the files extracted into folder

> c:\development\referencebuilds\qt\4.7.4\qt-everywhere-opensource-4.7.4

3, Copied back all files from the folder

`c:\development\referencebuilds\qt\4.7.4\qt-everywhere-opensource-4.7.4` to `c:\development\referencebuilds\qt\4.7.4\`

4, ran

> configure.exe -opensource -fast -no-acce ssibility -no-qt3support
>   -no-multimedia -no-audio-backend -no-phonon -no-phonon- backend
>   -no-webkit -no-scripttools -platform win32-msvc2008 -D
>   "_BIND_TO_CURRENT
>   _VCLIBS_VERSION=1"

5, nmake and now I get the following errors.

`C:\development\referencebuilds\qt\4.7.4\bin\qmake
 C:/development/referen cebuilds/qt/4.7.4/\projects.pro  -o Makefile
 -spec win32-msvc2008 Could not find mkspecs for your
 QMAKESPEC(win32-msvc2008) after trying:`

`C:\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs Error processing project file:
 C:/development/referencebuilds/qt/4.7.4//projects .pro NMAKE : fatal
 error U1077: 'C:\development\referencebuilds\qt\4.7.4\bin\qmake.EX E'
 : return code '0x3' Stop.`

I have no clue as to why it is refering to C:\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs . How do I get over this error? what is exactly happening. How do I prevent such issues in future?

Comment: There is an environment variable that tells `qmake` where to look for spec files...you should check your environment variables to make sure it's not getting confused by that.

Comment: @Keith - what is that variable?

Comment: Did you extend the PATH to include your $(QTDIR)\bin directory? Also, if you are using a regular console rather than a Visual Studio command prompt, you'll have to run Visual Studio's vcvars.bat to have the proper environment variables set.

Comment: @Gnawme - Yes I have. I am using Visual Studio command prompt.

Comment: Ah. I just read through your edits. Try copying the mkspecs folder from the source directory to your install directory and run 'configure' again.

Comment: @Gnawme - I believe they both are the same.Just read edit 2 in entirety, the others are not irrelevant now.

Comment: OK. Looks like you need to set the $(QMAKESPEC) environment variable to be win32-msvc2005. I added it to my answer. (Hope it works...)

Answer (score 2):

Your install directory is:

> c:\development\referencebuilds\qt\4.7.4\qt-everywhere-opensource-4.7.4

Let's call it $(QTDIR). Now:

1. Extend your PATH variable to include $(QTDIR)\bin
2. Specify the QMAKESPEC environment variable to be win32-msvc2005
3. Open a Visual Studio command prompt to get the Visual Studio environment variables
4. Run configure
5. Run nmake

This procedure usually gets the Qt build to work for me.

Comment: +1: Indeed, don't add the source directory's bin directory to PATH, it's empty (or doesn't contain what you're looking for), qmake is built when you call `configure`.

Comment: Issue persists, after adding QMAKESPEC - win32-msvc2008. Error is:
Microsoft ® Program Maintenance Utility Version 9.00.30729.01
Copyright © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
C:\development\referencebuilds\qt\4.7.4\qt-qt\bin\qmake C:/development/r eferencebuilds/qt/4.7.4/qt-qt/\projects.pro -o Makefile -spec win32-msvc2008 ‘C:\development\referencebuilds\qt\4.7.4\qt-qt\bin\qmake’ is not recognized as a n internal or external command, operable program or batch file. NMAKE : fatal error U1077: ‘C:\development\referencebuilds\qt\4.7.4\qt-qt\bin\qm ake’ : return code ‘0×1’ Stop.

Comment: Have you considered starting over from scratch? qmake isn't present until the configure command has completed successfully. (When I do have problems installing Qt, it's normally because I didn't run from the Visual Studio command prompt.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't have any existing QT directories in your path before you call configure and nmake.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a previous version of Qt installed. "C:\Qt\4.7.2\". And it would seem you have it setup in your system variables. Look for a variable called QTDIR in your system environment variables. Which is why you are getting an error, basically your 4.7.2 Qt is trying to build the new version.

Two options:

Un-install your old Qt via add/remove software in the control panel.

or

Remove your QTDIR system variable for the time being (will require a re-login) so that when you try to build from source it will use the correct binaries from the source folder.

Then just follow this guide:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Opticks_Developer_Guide/Getting_Started/Building_Qt_From_Source